# Header file with constant arrays initialized with functions

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I have a header file in which I have some constants like `uint64_t knight_attacks[64]` or `uint64_t king_attacks[64]`. To initialize these constants, I first processed the values I needed with a Python script and then just wrote it directly like `king_attacks[64] { ... explicit values };` but I had troubles with this so I decided to directly build the arrays in my code.

It gives this:

```
typedef uint64_t bitboard;

inline bitboard* get_knight_attacks()
{
    static bitboard attacks[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        attacks[i] = 0;
        for (int m: {i - 17, i - 15, i - 6, i + 10, i + 17, i + 15, i + 6, i - 10})
            if (m >= 0 && m <= 63 && abs((i % 8) - (m % 8)) <= 2)
                attacks[i] |= m;
    }
    return attacks;
}

inline bitboard* get_king_attacks()
{
    static bitboard attacks[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        attacks[i] = 0;
        for (int m: {i - 9, i - 8, i - 7, i + 1, i - 1, i + 7, i + 8, i + 9})
            if (m >= 0 && m <= 63 && abs((i % 8) - (m % 8)) <= 1)
                attacks[i] |= m;
    }
    return attacks;
}

const bitboard knight_attacks[64] { *get_knight_attacks() };
const bitboard king_attacks[64] { *get_king_attacks() };
```

However it looks makeshift to me and **I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this.**

I had to add the `inline` not to get a "multiple definition" error and the `static` to be able to initialize my arrays with the returns of my functions.

I thought about using vectors but I don't think it is cleaner, especially in the upcoming code where I will need 2D arrays (64 * 64).

Comment: Why put these in headers at all? You should be abalr to go back to your initial idea of pre-defined arrays if you read up on `extern` and `static` Not sure which one best suits your case.

Comment: I need to be able to quickly modify the arrays, I don't want to be forced to run the Python script and copy/paste all the data for each small change.

Comment: You might wanna get comfortable with constexpr.

Answer (score 1):

To make it cleaner, i think you can :

- Use `std::array` STL container like this : `const std::array<bitboard, 64> knight_attacks = get_knight_attacks();` and make your functions return `std::array<bitboard, 64>` data type. It has the advantages of erasing the use of pointer, and provinding the same thing C array provide, with the addition of several useful functions ( like `begin()`, `end()`, `at()`, which can be used with some other STL algorithms like `std::for_each`, `std::find`... )
- Define functions in cpp file, and let the function declaration in header files. If you had "multiple definition" errors, it's because you tried to define functions in header files, while functions and variable definitions should normaly be in cpp files ( except the `inline` and template functions ), like this :

in header file, the function declaration :

```cpp
std::array<bitboard, 64> get_king_attacks();
```

and in cpp file, the function definition :

```cpp
std::array<bitboard, 64> get_king_attacks()
{
    std::array<bitboard, 64> attacks;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        attacks[i] = 0;
        for (int m: {i - 9, i - 8, i - 7, i + 1, i - 1, i + 7, i + 8, i + 9})
            if (m >= 0 && m <= 63 && abs((i % 8) - (m % 8)) <= 1)
                attacks[i] |= m;
    }
    return attacks;
}
```

and then, for the variable initialization :

```cpp
const std::array<bitboard, 64> knight_attacks = get_knight_attacks();
```

> I first processed the values I needed with a Python script and then just wrote it directly like king_attacks[64] { ... explicit values }; but I had troubles with this so I decided to directly build the arrays in my code. )

- If you still want to use this technique, you can do like that :

in header file, the global variable definition :

```cpp
const std::array<bitboard, 64> knight_attacks;
```

and in the cpp file, the variable definition :

```cpp
const std::array<bitboard, 64> knight_attacks = { ... explicit values };
```

Hope this help